# Winforms MessageBox font

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-10

I am trying to create an InputBox class in C# similar in appearance and function to the built-in MessageBox. One of the big differences now is in the font of the body text:

[image]

The dialog in the middle is the built-in MessageBox. The one on the top is mine, with the font as MS Sans Serif, 9pt. The bottom one is also mine, with font MS Sans Serif, 8.25pt. Using any size in between results in rounding. I have tried using Tahoma, but that didn't match either.

What is the font MS uses in their Win10 dialogs?

P.S. I'm aware VB has something similar to this, but I am not using it since I found it ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemfonts.messageboxfont):

```
label.Font = SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont;
```

This is better than using a specific font name, because the font of the message box may be customized by the user. Using `SystemFonts` you always use the values the user has defined on his/her machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MS Shell Dlg 2`. Windows will map it to the one that the current version of Windows is using.

Comment: I'm unable to find this font as an option in the VS2017 properties pane. Should I use this directly in the code? Could you provide an example?